# (Android Studio) Java - Why is my If Else Validation not Working?

Tags: java, android-studio, validation, input, radio-button

```
public void Calc(View v) {
    radioButton = findViewById(R.id.byjY);

    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResultDisplay);
    EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextBYJnextpageq2);
    float n1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());

    // This is the line that have error
    if (et1.getText().toString().length() == 0 || radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Inputs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } // The line above is not working. If I removed the above codes however, it works fine

    else if (radioButton.isChecked() && !et1.equals("")) {
        float totalML = 2000 * n1; //one month = 2000ml = 4 bottles
        float totalBottles = totalML / 500;
        float totalDays = totalML / 60; //total volume / 60ml (per day)
        //Toast.makeText(BYJpage2.this, "Go Go Power Rangers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        result.setText("Batman");
    } else if (!radioButton.isChecked() && !et1.equals("")) {
        float totalML = 1000 * n1; //one month = 1000ml = 2 bottles
        float totalBottles = totalML / 500;
        float totalDays = totalML / 30; //total volume / 30ml (per day)

        result.setText("Superman");
    }
}
```

The objective is to check if the radio buttons (radio group) and the edit text from the user inputs are empty. If empty, user will get an error message from the Toast.makeText.

However, I'm unable to solve the problem. Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: While I can't help you with a solution. It is often good to add a final else statement (even if it should not happen) and check there what you get and why the other statements failed.

Answer (score 0):

You're directly comparing the `EditText` object to an empty string, when what you really want is to compare the **contents** of the `EditText` to an empty string. You need to get text from the `EditText` properly. Instead of:

```
!et1.equals("")
```

try:

```
!et1.getText().toString().equals("")
```

If you let your user freely enter text, sometimes they get fat fingered and add extra whitespace, so you can always add a call to `String.trim()` right after the `toString()` call.

Comment: Hi, I tried this method. Unfortunately it didnt worked.

Comment: @Jane Well, at the very least, this answer addresses one of what are probably many problems you're having. The real problem here is an issue of communication. If you just tell me "It didn't work," that doesn't tell me anything. You have to troubleshoot your program to identify the actual problem. I'd start by adding LogCat lines to indicate what is actually in the edit text, and I'd also add an `else` clause to your `if... else if` statement because you are obviously not meeting the conditions that you think you should be meeting.

Comment: @Jane Before you begin, read this article about [how to debug programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Stack Overflow requires that you at least identify the actual problem you're facing before asking a question to avoid cascading issues, just like we're seeing here. Remember that it's very difficult to hit a moving target, so if you keep changing the issue, you're unlikely to see a resolution. We're relying on you to provide an accurate assessment of what the actual problem is when you ask -- if you don't do that, it just gets messy.